# how to access something sent to the super class

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, super

```
public class BattleEvent extends EventObject {

    private BattleEventType type;
    private BattleOpponent currentOpponent;
    private BattleOpponent winner;
    private Attack attack;
    private Collectible collectible;


    public BattleEvent(Battle battle, BattleEventType type) {
      super(battle);
      this.type=type;
     this.currentOpponent=battle.getMe();
    }
```

i have battleevent object in another class i want to access the battle i sent it to the eventObject how can i access it ?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to access the battle i sent it to the eventObject

Based on `super(battle)`, you should have a constructor that looks like

```
public EventObject(Battle battle)
```

How you handle that parameter is "how you access it"

Answer (score 0):

EventObject needs to expose it as a protected member or have an accessor (a getter method) for it.